# Port Upstart Script to Systemd

Tags: segmentation-fault, upstart, systemd, ubuntu-15.10

I cam currently building a miniroot with an Ubuntu 15.10 base. Therefore I want to use systemd.
My standard script '/etc/init.d/script' is found and executed by systemd.
However I also do have a conf for this script located at /etc/init/script.conf is not executed. Therefore I write this systemd script

```
[Unit]
Description=Job that starts the startmaster.sh in /usr/bin/local/
Requires=script.service
After=script.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/sbin/getty -l /usr/local/bin/startmaster.sh -n 38400 tty6

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

this script is executed on boot, but it does not show the expected behaviour

content of startmaster.py
    #!/bin/sh

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

#vt=$1
vt=6


sleep 1
chvt $vt
sleep 1
chvt $vt
sleep 1
chvt $vt

screen -U master.py

exec getty 38400 tty$vt
```

dmesg shows the following segfault

```
[ 2106.122116] master.py[3960]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f731ccfa892 sp 00007ffdb76d5620 error 4 in libc-2.21.so[7f731cc76000+1c0000]
```

any suggestions how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need the getty and vt complexity. Does `master.py` require human input? Why no just run `master.py` directly from the systemd unit? If you need to monitor it, you can do that by viewing the output from `master.py` by running `journalctl -u master.service`.

This is much simpler. Please try it and see if it suites your needs

```
[Unit]
Description=Master service that does xyz

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/master.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: in case some infos are not given the user need to complete them, therefore I need the human interaction.

Comment: I tried it your way and got the following error....
master.py[3847]: TERM environment variable needs set....Failed with result'exit'code'